# SuiteScript 2 Bundle Company Preference

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I have to add a field to the company preferences of an instance, from my understanding I have to do this with a bundle. I have no idea of what record type to target or how to add a field to it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Too ambiguous to answer..please clarify.  There are a few ways to add a custom preference at that level.  The lowest hanging fruit is probably to create a *script parameter* with `preference` of "company". Do you have a script?

Comment: In the company preferences section setup>company>general preferences I have to add an integer field, and later access that from a client script. the field carries the max amount of items that can be chosen from a list on an item record. I have to validate against that number, thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add field with *company preference*, you need to create a script parameter in any of the scripts that are included in the said bundle and not on any record. [Here](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=chapter_n2999459.html) is example for the same. This script-paramter will be available under **setup>company>general preferences** and can hold any values that you want.

Comment: Hi and thanks, I understand how to create a script parameter, but I need to add an attribute (integer field) to the "general preferences" section of "setup>company>general preferences",  I apologize if I seem dense but how would that work? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by **add an attribute**? do you want to set an integer value in the script  param or set a fieldId in the script param? or do you wan to know how to set the value in it?

Comment: The suggestion of the script param was the first commenter, I must not have been clear. I need to add a text box that takes an integer, for Max Items for another application I am creating. I am modifying BOMS to accept configurable items and I need to establish a way to change the max number of options that can be applied to an item in the BOM. This will be an attribute or field that can be edited on in the general preferences section of setup>company>general preferences. I hope that makes it clearer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Create a script parameter with its preference set to _Company_(this script paramter will hold the value of integer or any other datatype that you want), this will create a field which can be updated from  **setup>company>general preferences**

Comment: I think I may have this figured out, if I create a bundle and add to the bundle script a company level param it will have it to the form? is this correct? thanks

Comment: If you would like please add as answer so I can give you credit, thanks very much